# How to show localization induces a topological embedding on Spec?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, localization, affine-schemes

The answer on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99312/krull-dimension-and-localization)
says that, for $A$ a ring and a multiplicative subset $S \subset A$, then $\operatorname{Spec}(S^{-1}A)$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, I assume via the map $f : \operatorname{Spec}(S^{-1}A) \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ induced from the localization map $A\rightarrow S^{-1}A$.

Already I understand why $f$ is a continuous injective map.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a reference that describes how to show $f$ is also a homeomorphism onto its image?

Comment: Potential duplicate, see the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154805/on-spec-of-a-localized-ring

Comment: @Arkady Thank you, this was very helpful.